# Change / Swap Bound Object on XAML page?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8.1

**Background:**

In an attempt to learn WP 8.1 development (non SL) I am building a Quiz app aimed at children. It is a Fruit guessing game.

**How it ought to work:**

User is shown a picture of a fruit along with three words. One of those words is the name of the fruit. If the correct word for the fruit is chosen, then the user gets a point and is also shown the next fruit with word options.

**What's the problem:**

I am new to WP 8.1 development and I am not really sure how to swap the bound `QuestionVM.cs` on the XAML page when the User selects the correct answer. Here is a diagram I put together of what I currently have:

[image: QuestionVM binding]

That whole QuestionVM needs replacing when the user selects the correct answer.

How do I do that?

Is there even a way to do that? Or must I change the **actual properties** on the `QuestionVM.cs` rather than swapping the whole `QuestionVM.cs` instance?

Comment: i wondering if you want to give the user the next task after the correct input?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Eventually, there would be a bar at the bottom telling the user how many points they have. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: sorry but what is your error?

Comment: My question doesn't have an error. I just need to know how I can swap the ViewModel instance attached to the XAML.

Comment: Oh like dynamic XAML like each page have a new XAML?

Comment: Nope, One XAML, but multiple instances of the ViewModel `QuestionVM.cs`.

Comment: Well i found few things that i hope it help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379998/multiple-instances-of-a-viewmodel  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039126/how-to-have-multiple-unique-instances-of-viewmodel-using-mvvm-light  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914860/how-to-have-multiple-instances-of-the-same-viewmodel-in-mvvm-light

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a `MainVM` on top of your QuestionVM. This will be the back store of your main screen.
2. Create a private `List<QuestionVM>` in `MainVM`. This will store all question objects in it.
3. Create a readonly `CurrentQuestion` property of type `QuestionVM`. This will point to the current question object.
4. Keep an private integer index for the current question.
5. Create `MoveNext`, `MovePrevious` commands (`RelayCommand` type) in `MainVM`. Call these upon the selection of correct answer (or through explicit buttons whatever you need).
6. These commands will simply increment/decrement the current index and then call `RaisePropertyChanged` on `CurrentQuestion` property. This will update your UI.

Note: I'm assuming you're using MVVM Light or some other MVVM framework and that your VM classes inherit from `ViewModelBase` or `ObservableObject`.